# Create a non-linear cluster of items in a list?

Tags: python

first post so please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.
I'm working in python (Spyder 3.2 on Mac) and I'm trying to create a list with values that are non-linear.
I want to get an output to look something like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 600, 601, 602, 603, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1203,...]
```

The length of the list and the steps between the variables will vary depending on other variables in the file I'm reading in.

What is the best way to create a list like this?

Comment: Define some range... Do `a.append(num)` for each num in the range. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

you can add an element to the end of a Python list with the append function. For example

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 600, 601, 602, 603]
a.append(1200)
print(a)
```

would output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 600, 601, 602, 603, 1200]`. You can set up your program flow around that however you would like to make sure your other variables take on the value you want them to.

Alternatively, depending on how the values of your other variables are calculated, you may be able to rewrite your list declaration as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or multiple nested list comprehensions. For example, a list of the perfect squares less than 401 can be generated like so:

```
a = [x*x for x in xrange(21)]
```

In this line of thought, if you can fit a function to your data you can generate your list with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = list(range(1,5,1)) + list(range(600,604,1)) + list(range(1200,1204,1))
print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 600, 601, 602, 603, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1203]
```